# How to connect project without web3 js npm package

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

I'm working with ASP.NET Core project and wanted to connect Blockchain with it. But the problem is, we don't want to use Web3 npm packages. Hence, I have added web3 js as follows

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

Now, I'm trying to set Web3 provider (Ganache Server URL) as follows,

```
const web3 = new Web3("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545");
```

But It gives an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: Web3 is not defined`

Is there any thing need to add in the above steps?

Comment: Ganache is unrelated of this problem. You can remove the corresponding tag and change the title accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! @goodvibration, updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use npm to work with web3 in .Net based project. You can use [nethereum](https://nethereum.com/)